# When does .Net run on UNIX?

Tags: .net

I've heard of mono for developing cross platform .Net applications but why does the .Net Framework itself include conditional compilation, for example

```
#if PLATFORM_UNIX
...
#endif // PLATFORM_UNIX
```

as can be seen in the .Net Framework Reference Source for System.IO.Path

Comment: Perhaps Microsoft had considered a unix port at some point but never completed it? This is something that probably nobody not under NDA can answer definitively...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for the [SSCLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_Source_Common_Language_Infrastructure), which uses much of the same codebase and can run on UNIX

Comment: Thanks, "Microsoft provides the Shared Source CLI as a reference CLI implementation suitable for educational use" I didn't know that's what the 'Reference Source' was.

Comment: @panamack: The SSCLI and the .Net reference are two different things.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to take a wild guess and go with what you are seeing is relics from Rotor, the FreeBSD implementation of .NET from way back in the day.

IIRC Rotor was somehow related to the conversion effort of Hotmail when MS bought that company.

Comment: from SLaks link "The Shared Source Common Language Infrastructure (SSCLI), previously codenamed Rotor," so +1 good memory :)

Answer (score 0):

From the source code of SSCLI, we can figure out the CLR is very easy to support other platforms if MS want to.